# Crystal Report Free in Visual Basic 2010 Express

Tags: visual-studio, crystal-reports, visual-studio-express

Is there a way to install Crystall Report Free on Visual Basic 2010 Express? I need to create and print some report on some Win-Form applicaton. If it's not possible, are there other free solutions?

Comment: Dear down-voter, please explain why you down-voted this question.  Until then, I'm going to up-vote it to cancel it out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Crystal Reports only works with standard editions or higher of Visual Studio.
Also worth noting is that the express edition does not support reporting.

Information obtained from [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/is/vblanguage/thread/92a489b0-667a-4f26-aa94-24e0feb79624) and [here](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/14200/reporting-in-visual-studio-2010-express)

Answer (score 0):

I know this may be a too late answer, but following [this example](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?717175-How-to-use-Report-Viewer-with-Visual-Studio-2012-Express) I could display SQL Server Report Builder files (.rdl renamed to .rdlc) via Report Viewer on Visual Studio Express 2012 on Windows7 both Web and Desktop. Make sure to read the bottom comments on the link's post related to where to get the DLL's on the local system.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code you can use:

The report file is `crystalreport1`.

Create a command button on the form where the crystal report is attached. Double click and write as follows :

```
Imports CrystqlDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine
Public class Form1
         Private sub Button1_click(ByVal sender As System.object, ByVal e As Sysyem.EventArgs) Handles Button1.click
             Dim CrystRpt as New ReportDocument
             CristRpt.Load('crystal report path\Crystalreport1')
             CystalReportViewer1.ReportSource=CristRpt
             CrystalReportViewer1.Refresh()
         End sub
end class
```